# How to do Password validation in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on password validation.
I am unable to get how to validate and show error when the password won't match.
Can anyone please guide me how to do it?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bynaK/361/)

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.serializeFormJSON = function () {

    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: code shown has nothing to do with validation. There are lots of tutorials and available scripts for this ... let google be your friend

Answer (score 0):

You can just add

```
 if(o['password'] != o['ConfirmPassword'])
    {
        alert('password incorrect');

    }
```

after .each() function to do validation

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bynaK/362/)